# Default Wordpress Favicon still showing after changing

Tags: php, wordpress, favicon

I've set a new site up on wordpress and am close to going live however I need to solve the issue before I can launch.
I have added in a favicon via appearance / Customise / site identity, However when the site loads it shows the default Wordpress favicon for about half a second before switching to my custom favicon. The custom favicon is the recommended size and I have also added
`<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="site.com/wp-content/uploads/favicon.png" />`
to the header.php file.

Has anyone had this same issue or knows how I can override the default Wordpress favicon from showing at all please.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear cache of your web browser and see if it fixes the problem. If not, first convert your favicon to .ico format(google it: favicon generator) and place at the root of your domain (e.g. http://www.yourdomain.com/favicon.ico)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to replace/add favicon on root (`site.com/favicon.png`) and don't set him on settings and don't add `<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="site.com/wp-content/uploads/favicon.png" />`. Browser will use it from default.

Comment: Hi Ivan, Thanks for your response. Surely i'd have to link site.com/favicon.png in the header for it to get pulled?

Comment: It was just an example. I think, if you will place your favicon file on `<rootDir>/favicon.ico` it will work for you.

Comment: It's still pulling the default

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the way I fixed it was accessing the source folder of my website (you can find yours in the control panel of your web host, call them if you can't locate it, that's what I had to do myself since I've always worked with WordPress and it was already installed in my plan)

Once you're there look for the folder that contains wp-admin and so on, that folder should have the same name as your website ( Forexample.com the folder would be named "Forexample" ) , in there you'll find a specific file named "favicon.ico" , you need to override it by uploading your own icon with the same name directly into that folder ( google 'favicon generator' , the website will give you many files that you'll also have to upload in that same folder for various devices/browsers ) After that you'll never see the WordPress icon again ( To make sure that you've overridden the file type 'yourwebsite.com/favicon.ico' in any browser, Yourwebsite being the name of your website, if you do it before overriding the favicon.ico file you'll see a WordPress icon, EVEN if you've already changed that icon within WordPress using the customizer, but after having overridden the file you'll now see your own icon, voilà. The WordPress icon is gone for good